# React-hook-form devtools with vite module federation

Tags: react-hook-form

I want to use react-hook-form devtools in the remote app, but I can't get it to work, possibly because of this: https://github.com/react-hook-form/devtools/issues/140

```
__federation_shared_react.js:35 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
```

Is there a known workaround for this or any idea how to solve this?

I have a repo set up for this [here](https://github.com/maangs/vite-mf), it's using Vite with Vite-plugin-federation

Answer (score 0):

I also arrived here searching for a similar issue to yours. In my case, things started working when I added react-hook-form to 'shared'. Additionally, if the operation isn't smooth, consider adding the 'eager' option as well."

Comment: @AhmedAbdelbaset: Why don’t you think it answers the question? They’re sharing what solved the problem for them.